# SharePoint 2013 - Creating 2 Page Libraries within the same Site Collection

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

With SharePoint 2013, is it possible to create a second Pages library within the same site collection?  Reason being is that I would like to set private user-permissions on this second library so that you can only see the pages if you are logged in "and" for the purpose of Google not crawling these pages to leave on search engine results.  These are basically private pages.

If this is possible, what steps are needed to create a 2nd pages library OOTB? I'm using Publishing Pages.

Thanks!

Comment: Heya! Not sure if you can even do that. At least for SP 2010 I think it's a "real" limitation to have only one pages library per publishing site. You could maybe try and use the wiki library and create wiki pages in it? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about creating a subsite under that Site Collection ? Subsites have their own Page library, and then exclude the whole Subsite or the Pages library from being crawled?

That would be my kind of OOTB "work-around".

Comment: Will do!  I'll just make sure to move my specific pages to the private sub site when the right time comes.  thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

You can create the pages library with the bellow steps-([Click Here for the reference](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/3a5c6718-7aae-4045-92d2-33ba4afe09ae/creating-another-site-pages-library-in-sp-2013?forum=sharepointgeneral#2cbc7c9e-b8fd-4553-967a-1d48b53ae765))

1. Click on Site Content
2. Click on add an App
3. Click on add a document library. Give it the desired name
4. When it loads, go into the document library settings
5. Advanced Settings
6. Allow managment of content types
7. Add the following content types (Page, Article Page, Welcome Page)
   plus any others in your Pages library
8. Delete the default Document Content Type

*Please note that SharePoint does not treat this newly created Pages library like the default Pages library. You can serve .aspx files from the new library, however it is not tied into the SharePoint infrastructure in the same way as the default Pages library is.*

Comment: This worked for me. Thanks :) After setting up 1 new pages library with this method, I created a template. Now I can just deploy the same solution via "add an app". Saves loads of time!

Comment: When I create new pages in this document library, they show up blank without any tools for editing or adding content. Anyone facing this issue?